# aggregateWindow works different than expected for the current day

Tags: aggregate, influxdb, flux, flux-influxdb

I accumulate data from my inverter on the daily PV production. I wanted to create a query to summarize production for each of the last 12 months. I have a problem with the current day: seems that it does not add the current day production to the current month.

The query I'm using is:

```
from(bucket: "home")
  |> range(start: -1y)
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>
    r._measurement == "inverter" and
    (r._field == "Power_PV_Generation_Today")
  )
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, offset: -1h1m, fn: last, createEmpty: false)
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1mo, fn: sum, createEmpty: true)
```

*Power_PV_Generation_Today* is a value extracted from the inverter and it resets at midnight - hence I'm interested in the *last* value for each day (the *offset* there is because I messed up setting the timezone while a preparing a container collecting the data, so part of the entries was recorded with a wrong timezone).

If I comment out the last line to get daily results, the current month looks like this:

| Time | Power_PV_Generation_Today |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-04 23:59:00 | 5.12 |
| 2023-01-05 23:59:00 | 2.95 |
| 2023-01-06 23:59:00 | 4.12 |
| 2023-01-07 23:59:00 | 5.74 |
| 2023-01-08 23:59:00 | 9 |
| 2023-01-09 23:59:00 | 2.15 |
| 2023-01-10 23:59:00 | 2.70 |
| 2023-01-11 23:59:00 | 8.47 |
| 2023-01-12 23:59:00 | 12.4 |
| 2023-01-13 15:51:51 | 3.13 |

I was expecting it to be summed up to 74.33, while the actual record of the full query for the current month is:

| Time | Power_PV_Generation_Today |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-13 15:54:27 | 71.2 |

Looks like the last value from the first *aggregateWindow* is disregarded for some reason.

Is there a way to include the record for the current day in the current month sum?

I've tried rephrasing the query in the following way:

```
from(bucket: "home")
  |> range(start: -1y)
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>
    r._measurement == "inverter" and
    (r._field == "Power_PV_Generation_Today")
  )
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, offset: -1h1m, fn: last, createEmpty: false)
  //|> aggregateWindow(every: 1mo, fn: sum, createEmpty: true)
  |> window(every: 1mo)
  |> sum()
  |> duplicate(column: "_stop", as: "_time")
  |> window(every: inf)
```

but the result was identical.

Comment: what version of influxdb are you running?

Comment: I'm trying it on 2.6.1 on Ubuntu installed from the official Influx repo.

Comment: What if you try to use the next day as stop time, like `|> range(start: -1y, stop: date.add(d: 1d, to: today()))`

Comment: Looks like this "hack" makes it work, thank you @alespour! Still not sure why aggregateWindow behaves like I observed, but at least now I have my panel working.